# If the value in the Hashmap does not match the webservice response then how can we handle that using java rest assured

Tags: java, automation, testng, rest-assured

By using HashMap I am trying to validate an XML response that I am getting by executing a webservice. I have put the inputs in a HashMap and captured the total part counts that is returned in the webservice response in a variable "count" which is of type "int". After that, the HashMap is iterated and then had another "for" loop with the "count" as the limit and checked that if the webservice response:
"partName" and input "partRevision" matches with the value taken from the HashMap then assert true else assert false.

But suppose there is a value in the HashMap which is not present in the webservice response, then is my code ok?

Please find the below code which I have written:

```
package com.ws.test;

import java.util.*;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class Test {
    
    @Test
    public void getList() {
        // Get response with the inputs
        Response response = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password").
                post("dummy value");
        response.print();

        // Verify response status 200
        int statusCode=response.statusCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode,200, "Mismatch in status code");

        String xml_string = response.asString();
        XmlPath xp = new XmlPath(xml_string);
        
        // Verify Message
        String actualMessage = xp.get("path");
        System.out.println("The actual message is: "+ actualMessage);
        Assert.assertEquals(actualMessage, "Success", "The api call failed");
        
        int count = xp.getInt("Path.size()");
        System.out.println("The total part count is: "+count);
        
        String pName;
        String pRev;
        boolean compare = false;
        
        if(count==10) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true, "Failure!!");
        }
        
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("part1", "rev1");
        hashMap.put("part2", "rev2");
        hashMap.put("part3", "rev3");
        hashMap.put("part4", "rev4");
        hashMap.put("part5", "rev5");
                    
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> hm : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            pName = hm.getKey();
            pRev = hm.getValue();
            //System.out.println(pName+" "+pRev); 
            
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
                String xmlPartName = xp.get("Part["+i+"].PartName");
                String xmlPartRev = xp.get("Part["+i+"].PartRevision");
                
                if(xmlPartName.equals(pName) && xmlPartRev.equals(pRev)) {
                    String partType = xp.get("Part["+i+"].PartType");
                                        
                    Assert.assertEquals(partType, "Test Part", "Part Type Mismatch!!");
                                        
                    compare = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    compare = false;
                }               
            }       
                Assert.assertTrue(compare); 
            }
            
        }   

}
```

Comment: Your `hashMap` is expected result, the response is actual result. If ther are mismtach then  fail the test. And Rest-Assured doen't help anything when comparing objects.